# Move between UIView and SKView

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I'm currently building a game which has menus, I decided to build the menus through storyboards and I have one view in SpriteKit. Here's how I currently transition

```
let currentViewController: UIViewController = (self.view?.window?.rootViewController)!

let next = currentViewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameOver") as! GameOverController

currentViewController.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The problem with this, is it only works once. Plus it can only be used when transitioning *from* an SKView. The error I get when I use the current method

> Warning: Attempt to present X on X whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Any ideas?

Comment: Log out or in the debugger, examine the class of `currentViewController`. I suspect the second time around it won't be what you expect, and may lead to enlightenment.